# select similar rows in excel 2011

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a spreadsheet in excel that has about 1500 rows and about 8 columns.  One of the columns is headed by 'orderable.'  Every cell in this column has either a value '1' or nothing at all.  I would like to select each row that has no value and delete the entire rows.  There are blank values elsewhere, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the entire column, use the Sort tool under the data section to sort by 0? Then they would at least be all touching. Would make it easier. I'm not aware of a way to delete a row based on a value in a column.

Comment: that works well for this...i was searching on it and it seems to need some form of SQL for a more specific selection

Comment: it is 'sort by value' for this instance, since '1' and null are being sorted, if anyone is curious.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to filter the data for the blank items, you can then delete all the rows which are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Select the *'orderable'* column. Type ƒ5 (or select Go To…). Choose Special…. Select 'Blanks'. At this point, all blank cells in your original selection should selected.

Right-click on one of the selected cells and click Delete. The resulting dialogue should offer 'Entire Row'. Select it and click OK. All the rows that are part of your selection will be deleted.

Note that if your range were smaller, you could just use CTRL-click to select a cell in each row that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but I think the original question is about deleting entire rows when on column in the row is blank and doing this "en-mass".

For Excel 2011:

1. Select an entire column (or row),
2. Under the "Edit" menu, select "Go To"
3. Select "special" in the dialog that pops up
4. Choose the "Blanks" radio button and click "Ok"
5. Now go back to the "Edit" menu and choose "Delete"
6. In the dialog box you should have the option for "Entire row"

Enjoy!